# NSURLSession access localhost:3000 always returns "Access denied"

Tags: heroku, ios-simulator, nsurlsession

I am building an iOS app and back-end server application and I can not access ***localhost:3000*** in the simulator with an `NSURLSession`.

When I move my app to heroku and change the base URL it works perfectly. But when I access ***localhost:3000*** I get an access denied.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried the ip address:3000 ?  I think localhost refers to the phone simulator itself.

Comment: Gave it a try... no difference with "http://10.1.10.22:3000".